# How can I export CDPATH avoiding issues with not-interactive shell scripts?

Tags: bash

To avoid issues with exporting CDPATH on non-interactive shells, I am trying to export CDPATH on my .bashrc as follows

```
if [[ $- == *i* ]]; then
    export CDPATH=.:~:~/cdpath
fi
```

I am running a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ $- == *i* ]] && echo 'Interactive' || echo 'not-interactive'
echo $CDPATH
```

resulting in

```
not-interactive
.:/home/user:/home/user/cdpath
```

Shouldn't the CDPATH content be empty?

Comment: Non-interactive shells, although they do not source bashrc on startup, still inherit their parents' exported variables. Just drop `export` from your bashrc and `CDPATH` will be empty in your script.

Comment: See: `help export`